# Formatting phone number with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I am creating a PDF form in Adobe Acrobat Pro and would like to format phone numbers using javascript so that a space is included after the area code and a hyphen is added after the prefix. I want to allow the user to enter extensions and other relevant info after the 10-digit phone number.

Below are a few examples of how phone numbers should be formatted:

```
Number Entered        Formatted Version
2125551212            212 555-1212
(212) 555 1212        212 555-1212
212-555-1212 ext. 101 212 555-1212 ext. 101
212 555 1212 x101     212 555-1212 x101
```

The code below should first strip out any spaces, hyphens, and other characters that are not digits or letters. That part seems to work OK, but the reformatting part of the code does not work properly. When a user adds an extension, the formatting is completely off. For example, 212 5551212 ext 339 becomes 212 5-5--1212 ext339.

```
{
f_val = event.value.replace(/\D\W[^\.]/g, "");
event.value = f_val.slice(0,3)+" "+f_val.slice(3,6)+"-"+f_val.slice(6);
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

(Please note, I am aware that this code does not validate and do not currently want it to do so.)

Answer (score 4):

If all the phone numbers are always like in your example, you can use a single replacement:

```
var re = /\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})/g; 
var subst = '$1 $2-$3'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, when I attempted to use this coding, the field was not automatically formatted.

Comment: @Ken: its strange, it works well for me, follow this link: https://eval.in/181848

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. I'll have to fiddle with your suggestion and see if I can get it to work right. So far, no luck.